# Type cannot be constructed: Exception

Tags: apex, exception

In Apex I have this:

```
...
if (forceException) {
   Integer a = 1/0;
}
...
```

But after I ran `SFDX Scanner` I got an error that variable `a` is defined but not used (UnusedLocalVariable) so I decided to do next thing:

```
...
if (forceException) {
   throw new Exception('Exception');
}
...
```

but now I had problem because `pipeline` throw me next error:

```
Type cannot be constructed: Exception
```

does anyone know is there any other option what I can use in if statement instead of `throw new Exception('Exception');` and `Integer a = 1/0;`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can create a custom Exception class, and throw an instance of that. For example:

```
class MyOwnException extends Exception{}
```

and then you can throw the custom exception.

```
if (forceException) {
   throw new MyOwnException('Exception');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For constructing user-defined custom exceptions as well as standard exceptions from your Apex class, you must extend the built-in Exception class and make sure your class (or child class) name ends with the word Exception. For instance, `MyException` or `MyCustomException`.

Here is an example of creating custom exceptions from the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_custom.htm).

```
public class ExceptionExample {
public virtual class BaseException extends Exception {}
public class OtherException extends BaseException {}

public static void testExtendedException() {
    try {
        Integer i=0;
        // Your code here
        if (i < 5) throw new OtherException('This is bad');
    } catch (BaseException e) {  
        // This catches the OtherException
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }  
  }
}
```

In the above example, we are using a `virtual class` (like Java) that extends built-in Salesforce's **Exception** and using it as a base class for inheriting all common Exception methods. By following the same approach, you could throw user-defined custom exceptions.

Also, please refer [Exception Class and Built-In Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) for more information.

Comment: You can also construct many of the standard exceptions, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can throw other Exceptions like `AuraHandledException('');` or `NullPointerException();`

Comment: In this case I get next error:
`Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void NullPointerException() from the type NamesOfMyClasses`